# How do you get the HTML source of a 500 code error page with PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

Normally when I run `$page = curl_exc($curlHandle)`. The page is returned. However if the page returns a `5xx` code `$page == False`.

Is it still possible to get the HTML contents of the page? I couldn't find it in `curl_info`.

This is for testing and I expect the page to return a 500 code.

Comment: If a 500 is returned there has been a server error and nothing will be rendered.

Comment: @JayBlanchard far from guaranteed.

Comment: True @Anonymous, but it is a majority case.

Comment: I am sure that it returns a content, its part of the specification to return json even if it is a 500 error. I see the output if i test it in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, from 500 to 599 (even unofficial [RFC status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)), it means some general server-side problem and the connection was **never** established or it was promptly **denied**. Of course, some people can still "force" entries in cases such as **509** (*Bandwidth Limit Exceeded*) or **511** (*Network Authentication Required*), by which the server isn't properly unavailable due to lack of connection, but set to be so, given some conditions (i.e. invalid credentials) that can be somehow faked.

You may receive data from the error page, though.